# Evaluate clustering labels using classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, clustering, model-evaluations

I've clustered 500 documents into 7 groups using K-means. Is this reasonable to use classification models to evaluate the clustering model?

What I would do is to get these 500 labelled documents using clustering. Then split into train and test and evaluate on classifier like NB? It achives f1_score of ~0.85. Using random labelling classification is obviously really bad.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think evaluating clustering output labels using classification makes sense. As if K means has created those cluster mostly they will be separable on the input classes. To Validate your clustering model you should be doing the following.

1. Look at Silhoutte Analysis for cluster = 7, and see if its well seprated
2. Do the profiling of all the variables to better understand the clusters and if they makes sense
3. Apply some business metrics to see if cluster behaves as you wnat them to